# Limit of the smallest eigenvalue of a series of symmetric Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I have tested by Matlab that for such a series of matrices $A_n \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $(A_n)_{i,j}=n-|i-j|$ (e.g.$A_3=\begin{bmatrix}3 &2 &1 \\ 2 &3 &2 \\ 1 &2 &3 \end{bmatrix}$), their smallest eigenvalues (denote as $(\lambda_n)_0$) are greater than 1/2, and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\lambda_n)_0=\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't know how to prove it. I only know that $$\det(A_n)=(n+1) *2^{n-2}$$
but I don't know it's useful or not.

In fact, I found this  while solving the second problem of the 39th CMO held today :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
A_n^{-1}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}
\begin{pmatrix}
n+2&-(n+1)&&&&1\\
-(n+1)&2(n+1)&-(n+1)\\
&-(n+1)&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&\ddots&2(n+1)&-(n+1)\\
1&&&&-(n+1)&n+2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By Gerschgorin disc theorem, all eigenvalues of $A_n^{-1}$ lie inside the interval $[0,2]$. It follows that $A_n$ is positive definite and $\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})\le2$. Now let $v=\big(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^{n-1}\big)^T$. Then $v^TA_n^{-1}v=2(n-1)+\frac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{n+1}$. It follows that $\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})\ge\frac{v^TA_n^{-1}v}{v^Tv}=\frac{2(n-1)}{n}+\frac{1+(-1)^{n-1}}{n(n+1)}$. Hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})=2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\min(A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})^{-1}=\frac12$.

**Remarks.** This example of $A_n$ in the OP is fairly interesting. To stress the dependence of the vector $\big(1,-1,1,-1,\ldots,(-1)^{n-1}\big)^T$ on $n$, let us denote it as $v_n$ instead of $v$. In the answer above, we have shown that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})=2$ and the Rayleigh quotient $\frac{v_n^TA_n^{-1}v_n}{v_n^Tv_n}$ approachs this limit when $n$ increases indefinitely. One may be tempted to think that $v_n$ is approximately an eigenvector of $A_n^{-1}$ corresponding to $\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})$ when $n$ is large. One may also expect it to be approximately an eigenvector of $A_n$ corresponding to $\lambda_\min(A_n)$, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{v_n^TA_nv_n}{v_n^Tv_n}$ exists and is equal to $\frac12$.

Surprisingly, none of these expectations is correct: the Rayleigh quotient $\frac{v_n^TA_nv_n}{v_n^Tv_n}$ is always equal to $1$! The vector $v_n$ is also far from being an eigenvector of $A_n$, in the sense that the elements of the entrywise division $(Av_n)\oslash v_n$ do not converge to $\frac12$. In fact, the first element of $(A_nv_n)\oslash v_n$ is equal to $\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil$, which diverges to infinity. The vector division $(A_n^{-1}v_n)\oslash v_n$ is more within expectation, though. It is equal to $(r_n,2,\ldots,2,r_n)^T$ where $r_n=\frac{n+2}{n+1}$ when $n$ is odd and $r_n=1$ when $n$ is even. All of its elements except the first and the last ones are equal to $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_\max(A_n^{-1})=2$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=1\ne2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! The inverse is important, with that we can estimate the eigenvalues easily without trying to find out what the smallest is. It's ingenious. Also I'm curious how you observed this inverse matrix? Is there some trick or knowledge I need to learn? Thanks again.

Comment: @ShuaiYang I did not foresee that $A_n$ has a nice inverse. I just tried and had luck.